# When can we use onDidExecuteCommand in our extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to use the new `onDidExecuteCommand` method but I don't see it listed on the API page.

Apparently it is [ready and merged](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/72345), so when can we use it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like it's not going to be available any time soon - the API has been in the ["proposed state"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api) for a while after being merged, but then some concerns came up that led to it being removed entirely for now:

> I have pushed [`21de711`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/21de711cdfb32d5798abbd60fc4ef92e640d23dd) that removes the proposed API - as explained in my previous comment. This wasn't an easy decision but there were too many doubts around the usefulness of this API, the performance impact, and accidental leakage of arguments.
>
> However, the internal API is there and we are open to accept features like the "keybindings teacher" or "macro recording" as a core contribution to VS Code.

*from [Finalize onDidExecuteCommand-API (#78091)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78091)*